# Mocking RenderingContext using Sitecore.FakeDB

Tags: unit-testing, sitecore, sitecore-mvc

I'm using Sitecore.FakeDB to write unittests for my Sitecore. I would like to mock the `RenderingContext`, to set the Rendering Parameters or Datasource of my current item.

However, when calling `RenderingContext.Current`, my unittest crashes with the following error:

```
Test method YourAssembly.YourClass.YourTest threw exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: Attempt to retrieve context object of type 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingContext' from empty stack.
```

Is mocking the `RenderingContext` supported by Sitecore.FakeDB?

If this is not supported, I'll abstract calls to RenderingContext away from my code using [Marc Duiker's blog](http://blog.marcduiker.nl/2014/11/18/isolating-calls-to-sitecore-context-part-1.html)

Comment: Don't think so. Items, security, pipelines, and settings seem to be the limit.

Answer (score 9):

How about use RenderingContext.EnterContext. Something like this:

```
Item datasourceContextItem = db.GetItem("/sitecore/content/some/stuff");

using (RenderingContext.EnterContext(new Rendering(), datasourceContextItem))
{

    IMyViewModelRepository repository = new MyViewModelRepository();
    MyController controller = new MyController(repository);

    ViewResult view = (ViewResult)controller.Index();

    ((MyViewModel)view.Model).MyHtmlStringProperty.ToString().Should().Be("some value");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You might not need FakeDb to set up a rendering context. As @gorhal has [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33829593/4207332), you should be using the `RenderingContext.EnterContext()` method:

```
[Fact]
public void EnteringSimpleRenderingContext()
{
  using (RenderingContext.EnterContext(new Rendering()))
  {
    Assert.NotNull(RenderingContext.Current);
  }
}
```

If you need *some* DataSource, you can create an item using either pure FakeDb

```
[Fact]
public void EnteringRenderingContextWithDataSource()
{
  using (var db = new Db { new DbItem("source") })
  {
    var contextItem = db.GetItem("/sitecore/content/source");
    using (RenderingContext.EnterContext(new Rendering(), contextItem))
    {
      Assert.NotNull(RenderingContext.Current);
      Assert.NotNull(RenderingContext.Current.ContextItem);
    }
  }
}
```

or FakeDb [integrated](https://github.com/sergeyshushlyapin/Sitecore.FakeDb/wiki/AutoFixture-Samples) with [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture):

```
[Theory, AutoDbData]
public void EnteringRenderingContextWithAutoDataSource(Item contextItem)
{
  using (RenderingContext.EnterContext(new Rendering(), contextItem))
  {
    Assert.NotNull(RenderingContext.Current);
    Assert.NotNull(RenderingContext.Current.ContextItem);
  }
}

internal class AutoDbDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
  public AutoDbDataAttribute()
    : base(new Fixture().Customize(
        new Sitecore.FakeDb.AutoFixture.AutoDbCustomization()))
  {
  }
}
```